# Upstart - run a command as another user while preserving /etc/environment

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, upstart

G'day,

I'm trying to run a command/service on startup with Upstart as a non-privileged user, while preserving /etc/environment.

I had some luck in a shell with

`exec sudo -u user1 -i "/usr/bin/foo /opt/bar >> /var/log/bar.log 2>&1"`

However, Upstart doesn't seem to like it (haven't been able to figure out why). I know the general advice is to use `su` and I had some success with that by manually sourcing a file like /etc/environment.local, but had problems getting Upstart to monitor the correct PID (it kept going after bash, instead of `/usr/bin/foo`, thus the attempt at sudo.

Any advice would be a huge help. I'm on Amazon Linux on EC2.

Answer (score 3):

Just source the /etc/environment file into your upstart script ?

```
if [ -e /etc/environment ]; then
    . /etc/environment
fi
```